# Windows Symbol Address Definition

Tags: windows, windbg, system-calls, windows-kernel, dependency-walker

I have extracted a dump file of system call addresses called in windows using ETW. I had some confusions about the addresses. I just use NtOpenFile for future examples.

### **1-**

I dump the Kernel PDB file received from Microsoft symbol server (ntkrnlmp.pdb) using cvdump. it's entry for NtOpenfile is like this:

```
S_PUB32: [000D:000DF320], Flags: 00000002, NtOpenFile
```

Then I open ntoskrnl.exe using Dependency Walker (DP). I scroll down and see the entry for NtOpenFile:

[image]

Then I receive the Kernel Base address using this little piece of code:

```
hNtdll = GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll");
NtQuerySystemInformation = (NtQuerySystemInformationFunc)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "NtQuerySystemInformation");
NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemModuleInformation, &ModuleInfo, sizeof(ModuleInfo), NULL);
KernelBase = (ULONG64)ModuleInfo.Modules[0].ImageBase;
```

The kernel base address is: `fffff802f7616000`

The actual address for NtOpenFile extracted using windbg is `fffff802f7b0e320 nt!NtOpenFile`

Adding the kernel base with address extracted from the pdb file gives me the wrong address (adding with the address from DP results correct). Why?

### **2-**

Why don't functions in win32k.sys like NtGdiFlush exist in the .sys file opened by DP? In Windows 10, there is another file named win32kfull.sys which contains those symbols but not in Windows 7.

### **3-**

I cannot map functions like NtQueryVirtualMemory at all. it exists in the ntkrnlmp.pdb dump, but as I said in part 1, the address seems wrong! And also it exists in ntoskrnl.exe opened by DP as ZwQueryVirtualMemory. But it differs from NtQueryVirtualMemory address extracted by windbg.exe
How do these map to each other? How can I extract this function's address using DP or PDB files?

### **4-**

How can I find win32k.sys system call addresses (like NtGdiFlush's address) using windbg?
the command `kd> x /D nt!Nt*` does not give me these symbol addresses.

Comment: `000D:000DF320` is in a logical segment:offset address where 0x000D is the PE section number. In the headers I see that section D is at offset 0x419000, and 0x419000 + 0xDF320 is 0x4F8320.

Comment: Thanks! But could you tell me how did you get the address 0x419000 from the headers? Which headers do you mean? Where can I find them?

Comment: You can use `dumpbin.exe /headers ntoskrnl.exe`; `link.exe /dump /headers ntoskrnl.exe`; or `cvdump.exe -headers ntkrnlmp.pdb`.

Comment: he probably means pe header you can do !dh modulebase  or use dumpbin module and look at the section start of segment D the 41 should be there

Comment: ntgdiflush etc are win32k apis either use x *!*nt*gdi* or qualify it with x win32k!nttab tab tab

Comment: Try .symfix+ and then .reload and see if that pulls down the matching OS symbols.

Comment: @blabb in windbg:  lkd> x !*ntgdi* : Couldn't resolve 'x '

Comment: x is a command followed by space  followed by modulename or an asterisk for wildcard followed by exclamation mark usually termed as bang followed by symbolname or a regex for partialname and hit enter  like  x  *!*abc* is the syntax

Comment: the forum is eating up asterisks in the comments  it is x asterisk bang asterisk regex

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what your use case is if it was just obtaining an address for an api from just a pdb file you could use the **dbh.exe** tool that comes with windbg package in batch mode

it loads the pdb at a default base (normally 0x10000000) and provides you the address of the api relative to that base

example

```
:\>dbh e:\SYMBOLS\ntkrpamp.pdb\E4AF624F009A4D99A4F85690E0164DBC2\ntkrpamp.pdb n ntopenfile

   name : NtOpenFile
   addr :  1232d81
   size : 0
  flags : 400000
   type : 0
modbase :  1000000
  value :        0
    reg : 0
  scope : SymTagPublicSymbol (a)
    tag : SymTagPublicSymbol (a)
  index : 1
```

you can confirm also with sysinternals livekd.exe

```
:\>livekd -b -c \"? nt!NtOpenFile;? nt; ? (nt!NtOpenFile-nt);q\" | grep -B 3 quit:
Evaluate expression: -2096693887 = 8306fd81
Evaluate expression: -2098999296 = 82e3d000
Evaluate expression: 2305409 = 00232d81
quit:

:\>dbh e:\SYMBOLS\ntkrpamp.pdb\E4AF624F009A4D99A4F85690E0164DBC2\ntkrpamp.pdb n ntopenfile

   name : NtOpenFile
   addr :  1232d81
   size : 0
  flags : 400000
   type : 0
modbase :  1000000
  value :        0
    reg : 0
  scope : SymTagPublicSymbol (a)
    tag : SymTagPublicSymbol (a)
  index : 1

:\>
```

as for as finding an api from all the loaded modules you can employ wildcards like *. etc

```
kd> x *!*ntgdiflu*
76cc5fd2          GDI32!NtGdiFlush (<no parameter info>)
98257991          win32k!NtGdiFlush (<no parameter info>)
9824c664          win32k!NtGdiFlushUserBatch (<no parameter info>)
kd> x Win*!*ntgdiflu*
98257991          win32k!NtGdiFlush (<no parameter info>)
9824c664          win32k!NtGdiFlushUserBatch (<no parameter info>)
kd>
```

It doesn't appear to be that simple as adding the S_PUB32 Value spat out by cvdump for a symbol to the segment offset

it seems that the S_PUB32 value was written before optimization function chunking etc all happened

cvdump in its headers has two different header information

one appears to be the actual header that is embedded in the final executable 
one one appears to be the original header pre optimization ? or whatever would be done after writing this header

```
E:\cvdump>cvdump.exe -headers ntkrpamp.pdb | grep -i original -A 500 | grep -i #8 -A 10 | grep -i virtual
  1A604E virtual size
  166000 virtual address

E:\cvdump>cvdump.exe -headers ntkrpamp.pdb | grep -i #8 -A 10 | grep -i virtual
  1AD618 virtual size
  16C000 virtual address
  1A604E virtual size
  166000 virtual address
```

the S_PUB32 value is added to the original segment offset 
in this case

```
E:\cvdump>cvdump.exe -p ntkrpamp.pdb | grep -i ntopenfile
S_PUB32: [0008:000620C8], Flags: 00000002, _NtOpenFile@24
```

**0x620c8** is added to **0x166000** the virtual address of `original header's section #8`  (this isn't reflected in dumpbin.exe /headers so dumpbin is kinda useless )

now omapf for this seems to show the actual function offset in the final executable

```
E:\cvdump>cvdump.exe -omapf ntkrpamp.pdb | grep -i 1c80c8
    001C80C8   00232D81
```

the pattern appears to be consistent for a few functions i tried

checking some random api

```
E:\cvdump>cvdump.exe -p ntkrpamp.pdb | grep -i rtlfreehot
S_PUB32: [0008:0011C32E], Flags: 00000002, _RtlFreeHotPatchData@4

E:\cvdump>cvdump.exe -headers ntkrpamp.pdb | grep -i original -A 500 | grep -i #8 -A 10 | grep -i virtual
  1A604E virtual size
  166000 virtual address

E:\cvdump>python -c "print \"%x\" % (0x11c32e+0x166000)"
28232e

E:\cvdump>cvdump.exe -omapf ntkrpamp.pdb | grep -i 28232e
    0028232E   002E88C0

E:\cvdump>dbh ntkrpamp.pdb n RtlFreeHotPatchData

   name : RtlFreeHotPatchData
   addr :  12e88c0
   size : 0
  flags : 400000
   type : 0
modbase :  1000000
  value :        0
    reg : 0
  scope : SymTagPublicSymbol (a)
    tag : SymTagPublicSymbol (a)
  index : 1

E:\cvdump>
```

if fpo data is available you can get the function size prolog no of params no of locals etc too

```
E:\cvdump>cvdump.exe -fpo ntkrpamp.pdb | grep -i 28232e
0028232E         2E        1        3        0     N   N    fpo        0
```

this exactly matches the windbg .fnent function output

```
kd> .fnent nt!RtlFreeHotPatchData
Debugger function entry 030b5b70 for:
(831258c0)   nt!RtlFreeHotPatchData   |  (831258
Exact matches:
    nt!RtlFreeHotPatchData (<no parameter info>)

OffStart:  002e88c0
ProcSize:  0x2e
Prologue:  0x3
Params:    0n0 (0x0 bytes)
Locals:    0n1 (0x4 bytes)
Registers: 0n0
kd>
```

Comment: My use case is to invoke a not-exported function in dll by its address in pdb.

Comment: for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416728/call-a-member-function-with-offset-address-from-dll