# Call a member function with offset address from Dll

Tags: c++, dll, reverse-engineering

I have non-exported member function in a dll.
I'm trying to call this function with **base + offset** address I extracted before.
I have a problem to do the actual calling from the class instance.

I I was able to get the base address of the module and the offset of the function from the dll.
I got an error calling the function because it not a member of my class.

```
HMODULE hDll = GetModuleHandleA("myModule.dll");

void *(funcPtr)() = (void(*)())((char *)&hDll + 0x101E07); //this is the non exported function address
myClassInstance->funcPtr();
```

I'm getting an error:

```
'funcPtr' is not a member of 'MyClass'
```

How do I make the call of `funcPtr` from `myClassInstance`?

Comment: It is not sensible code, you'd simply use `funcPtr()` to call the function.  If you want the variable to be a member of the class then declare it that way instead of using a local variable.  Do beware that this code [is very unreliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: So I can only call a static function in this way?
I can't add funcPtr to MyClass. 
That's a given class with no exported function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an simple thing to do.  First, you need to declare your pointer as a member function pointer:

```
void (MYCLASS::*funcPtr)();
```

And you'd call it via

```
(myClassInstance->*funcPtr)();
```

Then you need some way to store a value in there.  You can't cast a `char *` (or `void *`) pointer to a member function pointer.  You'll have to use some form of type punning.

The typical way is to use `memcpy`:

```
void *addr = (char *)&hDll + 0x101E07;
memcpy(&funcPtr, &addr, sizeof(void *));
```

Another possibility, since getting the address of the member function from the DLL is already over the line for Undefined Behavior, might be using a union:

```
union MemFuncPtr {
    void *addr;
    void (MYCLASS::*memfun)();
    // Can be expanded to include other member function pointer types if necessary
};
```

Then you can just

```
MemFuncPtr mfp;
mfp.addr = (char *)&hDll + 0x101E07;
funcPtr = mfp.memfun;
```

Or you can try the very ugly reference cast on the left side of the assignment.

There are additional possible complications if the function you're getting the address of is `virtual` and `myClassInstance` points to a derived class, or if multiple inheritance is involved.

Proceed at your own risk.